# Java sentence shortening program doesn't work right

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof, sentence

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SentenceShortener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = "";
        String sentence2 = "";
        String sentence3 = "";
        String finalcount = "";
        
        System.out.println("Input sentence ");
        
        sentence = kbd.nextLine();
        int space = sentence.indexOf(" ");
        System.out.println(sentence.substring(space+1));
        
        sentence2 = sentence.substring(space+1);
        int space2 = sentence.indexOf(" ");
        System.out.println(sentence2.substring(space2+1));
        
        sentence3 = sentence2.substring(space2+1);
        int space3 = sentence2.indexOf(" ");
        System.out.println(sentence3.substring(space3+1));
        
        finalcount = sentence3.substring(space3+1);
        
        System.out.println("Your " + sentence.length() + " character long sentence was shortened to " + finalcount.length() + " characters.");
    }

}
```

I created a program that should shorten four word sentences and longer down to decreasingly shorter "sentences" and counts how many characters you shortened the sentence to.

**Here is how it should work:**

```
Input sentence
The car runs good.
car runs good.
runs good.
good.
Your 18 character long sentence was shortened to 6 characters.
```

**How it actually runs:**

```
Input sentence 
The car runs good.
car runs good.
runs good.
 good.
Your 18 character long sentence was shortened to 6 characters.
```

**Another run:**

```
Input sentence 
Why is it raining?
is it raining?
t raining?
aining?
Your 18 character long sentence was shortened to 7 characters.
```

I'm a beginner with Java.

Comment: The actual output looks very much like your intended output. Perhaps you would like to spell out explicitly what the problem is with the output you are getting.

Comment: Look very carefully at which sentence you're getting the index of the first space character from in each case. The code you showed us is behaving correctly, it's just not behaving according to your expectations. That is because the code you wrote does not model those expectations correctly.

Comment: Please avoid terms like "doesn't work right" while describing technical problems. Just like when you go to a doctor you don't just say "*I am sick*", you also need to say *what makes you think so*.

Comment: I had to fix formatting on one of my examples of how it actually runs. The last line where it had "good." actually had a space in front of it in the console output.  The second example of how it runs chops of some characters.

Comment: If you want to preserve spacing post those examples using `code block` (like you did at start of your question).

Comment: Or wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags to avoid the colors of a code block. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Leonartist Clearly that is the sort of information you need to include in your question.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I'm kind of lost on what to fix with each space character. How do I make the program operate to my expectations?

Comment: @Leonartist You do `int space2 = sentence.indexOf(" ");` and `int space3 = sentence2.indexOf(" ");`. That is wrong if you intend `space2` and `space3` to hold the indexes where the first space occurs in `sentence2` and `sentence3` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic to determine index of space is incorrect.
Try modifying your code to have

```java
int space2 = sentence2.indexOf(" ");
int space3 = sentence3.indexOf(" ");
```